# Include (but do NOT compile) source file in project build

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, compilation, building

I have a Visual Studio ASP.NET C# Solution / Project setup like this:

```
> MySolution
    > MyProject
      * MyFolder
      * MyPages
      * MyScripts
      ...
      MyConfig.cs <-- This file
    ...
--- End MyProject / MySolution
```

I am having the project compile, but in the process it also compiles the MyConfig.cs file too when I need it to not do so.

This file contains several properties in various forms that are used throughout the application and I would like it to be **left in source code form** so that it could be easily **edited as plain text on the server** if need be without rebuilding / redeploying the solution / project.

I have tried messing with the file's properties, specifically "Build Action" & "Copy to Output Directory", by setting them to "Content" and "Always", "Compile" and "Always", "AdditionalFiles" and "Always" ... respectively. All without success. I am not sure where I need to make changes in order to achieve this behavior.

Any assistance or help is appreciated.

Comment: So I'll ask the obvious question:  Why are you using source code to manage configuration settings instead of using the built-in configuration subsystem? Source code seems prone to typos--think of how many times you break the build in a day just doing normal development...with the aid of an IDE...that has error highlighting.

Comment: If you're including the source code on the server, then how do you expect that to become part of the application? After the user makes a change, they're going to compile it *on the server*? That seems ridiculous. If it's an ASP.NET project, either use the .config file like every other application or create a settings.json file. Keeping it in C# when it doesn't belong there is silly.

Comment: If you are going to do something like this then you need to look into either Managed Extensibility Framework http://mef.codeplex.com/ or the CSharpCodeProvider class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx . Also, how to exclude files from build: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455.aspx

Comment: "Content"+"Copy always" will copy source to bin folder... But based on second half of the question it is very unclear what you actually expect to happen. " file contains several properties in various forms that are used throughout the application" hints on the fact you actually looking to compile the file, but the rest of the post claim it should not be compiled. Very confusing. In current state question likely need to be closed as "no longer repro" as steps you have actually achieve what you describe.

Comment: @KennethK. I never said I am managing "configuration settings" with this file. I am not sure where you got the idea from, but it manages things that cannot (no matter how much you try) be put into any .config file. I am not sure how a .config protects the app from errors more than any other file type, when in fact I can cause just as much damage in .config as in .cs or any file type.

Comment: Maybe from the file named "MyConfig"??

Comment: The goal of a config file is not to protect the application from errors. The point is that settings that need to change should not be stored in application code, they should be stored outside in some sort of file that doesn't require a compilation to change. You can create a code representation of your configuration, but the actual values should be read in from a file or database or something else easily updated.

Comment: @mason you missed my rebuttal to Kenneth's point. I was referring to Kenneth's point (of which I disagree with) that putting my properties in a .cs file makes the possibility of errors in the application (i.e. crashes or what not) from the config file increase dramatically versus using a .config file.

Answer (score 4):

You can just set the include tag to None like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="foobar.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the build type to content or none should be sufficient but intellisense won't always catch that change. You will need to close the file first before you rebuild. You can reopen it afterwards and it should not be compiled or error checked in the editor anymore.

Comment: @SC I tried this, but in cases where I reference the properties in MyConfig.cs, the project will not compile saying that the class/property does not exist (i.e. missing an assembly reference.) Do files that use MyConfig.cs need to be set to the "Content" build action too?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want them to compile either. Otherwise you have an inconsistent goal. If not, you need to consider some of the comments already posted in regards to why you are doing what you are doing and better approaches that might be available.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware, but you can make custom configuration sections backed by a model to allow the configuration file to match your complex configuration property types. You can still edit this on the server without rebuilding or repackaging (it will be turned into YourApplication.exe.config assuming this is an app.config you are talking about).

Comment: The config file is already bloated enough as is (this is a 10 year old site, that has had stuff piled on and on). I am trying to have a custom C# file that has various settings stored in it be used throughout the application/site without needing to recompile the entire project / solution as (or when) the C# file changes.

Comment: So why not put those settings in a database assuming your config already has the connection information? You can even change it during runtime there and don't need to worry about a convoluted hack like it sounds this is turning out to be. If you don't like databases you can use a json file as well. Or why not just add a reference to another configuration file in your current one and put your new settings in that one?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but after googling this for a while I found a solution so I thought I would post it here in case anyone else ends up reading this. I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-exclude-files-from-the-build?view=vs-2017) but it did not work as described.

I opened my csproj file is a text editor and changed the “Include” to “Exclude”. The project would not load in VS because “Include” is required. So tried adding Include=”” along with the “Ecxclude” and the project still wouldn’t load.

So then I realized that you can use a Condition to resolve this.

```
<Compile Include="folder\blah.aspx.cs" Condition="1==2" />
```